# Why doesn't the google plus user search api return any results?

Tags: google-plus

I'm having trouble with the google plus API.
Trying to use the [user search API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/search), all it returns is a selflink and structure data.
What am I doing wrong?

And how can I use this API by only sending a HTTP request?

Comment: what do you mean by selflink and structure data?

Comment: The selflink is URL containing the used address, which I by the way believe to be fairly useless here, and the "structure data" is simply the JSON stuff returned by default. Have a look: https://content.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people?query=bla&key=AIzaSyD-a9IF8KKYgoC3cpgS-Al7hLQDbugrDcw

Comment: Looks different now, but I still can't figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: It looks like it's working now.

Comment: Thanks abraham! I dont't even want to know why it wasn't working before...